# NoSuchLabelException: No such label: master

Tags: spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

I am configuring local git repository in spring cloud-config-server
But while I start application then I got the error "org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.NoSuchLabelException: No such label: master"

I tried to resolved it by adding below in application.properties file still giving same error
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=main

I am using spring-boot version '3.1.4'

```
spring.application.name=cloud-config-server
server.port=8888
#spring.profiles.active=dev
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri= file:///home/mayurj/Git/cloud-config
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=main
```

Comment: I also interchange the property as spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=master